# How to get number of hours between 2 System.currentTimeMillis()

Tags: java, android, swing, datetime

I have saved the record insertion time in `System.currentTimeMillis()`. Now at present time, I know the current `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

I want to know the difference between the 2 in terms of number of hours passed.

When i use this

```
System.currentTimeMillis()/(60 * 60 * 1000 ) - savedDate/(60 * 60 * 1000)
```

It gives me this number `414419` in output

Kindly guide me how to get number of hours from `currentTimeMillis`

Comment: Probably a re look at operator precedence?

Comment: First, I would subtract first and do the division afterwards. Otherwise rounding errors will sum up (there will be 1 hour from 9:59 to 10:01, but 0 hours from 10:01 to 10:59). Second, I wouldn’t want to do the division myself, that forces the reader to figure out where I got those numbers from. Using a library makes for clearer code. For example `Duration.ofMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() - savedDate).toHours()`, or see [Sujith Niraikulathan’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43345054/5772882)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add bracket arround the multiplication:

```
System.currentTimeMillis()/(60 * 60 * 1000 ) - savedDate/(60 * 60 * 1000)
```

Comment: This still giving me 414419 in output

Comment: number of hours between these 2 times

Comment: Figured this out. Thanks. 
This is the current value 1491911618956

Answer (score 6):

Try to use android's time util class to solve your problem

```
private long hourDifference(long millisFirst, long millisSecond) {
    return TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisSecond - millisFirst);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm");    
Date resultdate = new Date(yourmilliseconds);
System.out.println(sdf.format(resultdate));
```

Comment: Your answer makes no sense. With 7 200 000 milliseconds, I expect 2 hours. From your code I get `jan. 01,1970 03:00` on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you.

```
   long diffInMillisec = System.currentTimeMillis() - savedDate;
   long diffInSec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(diffInMillisec);
   seconds = diffInSec % 60;
   diffInSec/= 60;
   minutes =diffInSec % 60;
   diffInSec /= 60;
   hours = diffInSec % 24;
```